# Solve $\sqrt[3]{7x+19}+\sqrt[3]{7x-19}=\sqrt[3]{2}$ by algebraic methods

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was trying to solve this equation without using calculus.
Is it possible to be solved by elementary algebraic methods?

$$\sqrt[3]{7x+19}+\sqrt[3]{7x-19}=\sqrt[3]{2}$$

Comment: where does the first root end?

Comment: What happens if you raise both the third power, simplify, and square, simplify and solve.

Comment: yes it can solved by algebraic methods

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\sqrt[3]{q+\sqrt{p^{3}+q^{2}}}$, $v=\sqrt[3]{q-\sqrt{p^{3}+q^{2}}}$,

we have $y=u+v$ satisfying $y^{3}+3py=2q \ldots \ldots (*)$.

Take $y=\sqrt[3]{2}$, $q=7x$ and $p^{3}+q^{2}=19^{2}$ or $p^{3}=19^{2}-(7x)^{2}$.

Substitute into $(*)$,

\begin{align*}
  2+3\sqrt[3]{19^{2}-(7x)^{2}} \times \sqrt[3]{2} &= 2(7x) \\
  \sqrt[3]{19^{2}-(7x)^{2}} &= \frac{14x-2}{3\sqrt[3]{2}} \\
  19^{2}-(7x)^{2} &= \frac{(14x-2)^{3}}{54}
\end{align*}

By factor theorem or Cardano formula,

$\displaystyle x=\frac{7}{4}, \frac{-8\pm 3i\sqrt{15}}{7}$ subject to correct choices of cubic roots in the original equation.

**P.S.:**  May rewrite as $\sqrt[3]{19+7x}-\sqrt[3]{19-7x}=\sqrt[3]{2}$ for easy computer verification.

Answer (score 0):

powering by $3$ we get 
$$7x+19+3\sqrt[3]{7x+19}^2\sqrt[3]{7x-19}+3\sqrt{7x+19}(\sqrt[3]{7x-19})^2+7x-19=2$$
and we get
$$14x+3\sqrt[3]{7x+19}\sqrt[3]{7x-19}(\sqrt[3]{7x+19}+\sqrt[3]{7x-19})=2$$
$$14x+3\sqrt[3]{7x+19}\sqrt[3]{7x-19}\sqrt[3]{2}=2$$
can you proceed?